# Fitting parameters of a nonlinear equation to match experimental data

Tags: r, curve-fitting, nonlinear-optimization, non-linear-regression, model-fitting

I tried modifing code that I found here using the nls function for this simpler equation, but have been unsuccessful so far.

[image: Equation]

```
new_f <- function(a, t, t1, dt, m){
  1-exp(-a*((x-t1)/dt)^(m+1))
}

fit_d <- nls(y~new_f(a, t, -30, dt, m), start=list(a=1, dt=46, m=1))

Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) : 
  singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates
```

Can someone help with this with a step by step guide for dummies? Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!.

My data: t=θ and y=Y(θ)

```
t <- c(-30, -29, -28, -27, -26, -25, -24, -23, -22, -21, -20, -19, -18, -17, -16, -15, -14, -13, -12, -11, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89)

y <- c(0.0000, -0.0013, -0.0027, -0.0041, -0.0055, -0.0069, -0.0085, -0.0101, -0.0119, -0.0137, -0.0155, -0.0173, -0.0192, -0.0212, -0.0234, -0.0258, -0.0285, -0.0291, -0.0250, -0.0224, -0.0268, -0.0298, -0.0297, -0.0324, -0.0347, -0.0353, -0.0377, -0.0392, -0.0392, -0.0383, -0.0309, -0.0166, 0.0006, 0.0233, 0.0521, 0.0843, 0.1200, 0.1597, 0.1997, 0.2381, 0.2762, 0.3137, 0.3501, 0.3864, 0.4229, 0.4590, 0.4951, 0.5312, 0.5655, 0.5967, 0.6245, 0.6494, 0.6726, 0.6939, 0.7132, 0.7316, 0.7487, 0.7641, 0.7784, 0.7917, 0.8037, 0.8146, 0.8248, 0.8343, 0.8432, 0.8516, 0.8596, 0.8671, 0.8740, 0.8805, 0.8868, 0.8931, 0.8992, 0.9050, 0.9105, 0.9155, 0.9202, 0.9247, 0.9290, 0.9330, 0.9369, 0.9405, 0.9439, 0.9470, 0.9501, 0.9529, 0.9557, 0.9583, 0.9608, 0.9633, 0.9658, 0.9682, 0.9704, 0.9726, 0.9747, 0.9768, 0.9788, 0.9808, 0.9827, 0.9844, 0.9858, 0.9869, 0.9880, 0.9890, 0.9899, 0.9909, 0.9918, 0.9927, 0.9938, 0.9947, 0.9956, 0.9964, 0.9970, 0.9975, 0.9980, 0.9985, 0.9989, 0.9993, 0.9997, 1.0000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems:

- the x in new_f should be t
- the problem is overparameterized so that the parameters are not identifiable.  There are an infinite number of parameter combinations that satisfy the problem. In particular, a / dt^(m+1) can be replaced with a single parameter. To fix that remove dt, say, from the starting values and fix it at 46.

With those changes the code produces a result.

```
new_f <- function(a, t, t1, dt, m){
  1-exp(-a*((t-t1)/dt)^(m+1))
}

dt <- 46
fit_d <- nls(y~new_f(a, t, -30, dt, m), start = list(a = 1, m = 1))
fit_d
## Nonlinear regression model
##   model: y ~ new_f(a, t, -30, dt, m)
##    data: parent.frame()
##     a     m 
## 0.560 3.315 
## residual sum-of-squares: 0.3099
##
## Number of iterations to convergence: 13 
## Achieved convergence tolerance: 4.165e-06

plot(y ~ t)
lines(fitted(fit_d) ~ t, col = "red")
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for identifying the problems in this approach. But I can't set dt = 46. I need to find all three parameters a, m including dt.
For my approach, parameter (a) should be set between 2.3 and 6.9 (according to the literature).
In my main equation I need to find the thirteen parameters (a1, a2, a3, m1, m2, m3, dt1, dt2, dt3, t2, t3, B1, B2), considering θ1 = t1 at the beginning of the first combustion phase and I can get B3 = 1 - (B1 + B2), that allow me a better fit to my experimental data.
Is there a way to code this or where could I start?

Comment: What you are attempting to do is impossible.  The parameters are not identifiable.  It is like saying a+b=0 and what is a and b.  You can choose one arbitrarily and then the other can be determined as its negative. The parameters in the problem in the answer can't be determined by an any algorithm since there is no unique value.  You must set one of them or impose a constraint or change the formula to something else so they are identifiable if you want all three..  Regarding the bounds, nls can accept bounds. See ?nls

Comment: Note that the more complex formula in your post that did not have code may be identifiable so the issue may just be that it was simplified too much.

Comment: Thank you for expanding the explanation for a better understanding. For parameter (a) if I can impose a restriction between 2.3 and 6.9. I will review (? Nls). In order to have a first understanding of R encoding, the second equation was proposed. My goal is to get to code my first equation and obtain its parameters (ai, mi, ∆ti, βi, ti), to understand its behavior because my research focuses on these parameters.

Comment: A bound constraint is not sufficient. It is like saying a+b=0 and a is between 0 and 1.  That still doesn't pin it down.  The type of constraint that will work is to constrain a to equal dt, say, and then substitute a for dt so that there are 2 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the inspection of the shape of the curve one can observe :

For high values of x the shape appears of the exponential kind because quite linear in logarithmic scale for y :

[image]

For low values of x the shape appears of the linear kind :

[image]

If we try to combine the two parts of the curve with the Heaviside step function H(x)
the result is not very satisfying because the junction is not smooth as shown on the next figure :

[image]

In order to obtain a smooth curve one can replace the Heaviside function by a logistic function :

[image]

The above numerical values of the parameters are not optimized. For a better fitting one have to proceed with non-linear regression (This wasn't done ). A major difficulty of non-linear regression is to set good "guessed" values of the parameters to start the iterative calculus. That is why the above approximative values could be very usefull.

Comment: Thanks for inspecting the curve of my data, but I need to use the proposed equation since I need to study the behavior of these parameters (ai, mi, ∆θi, βi, θi) for my research.
Is there a way to code the equation and get the 13 parameters (a1, a2, a3, m1, m2, m3, ∆θ1, ∆θ2, ∆θ3, θ2, θ3, β1, β2)?